# How can I pre-emptively mute Steam event invitations?

Tags: steam

I happen to be a member of [some Steam group](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/stackexchange) that has been having a lot of events recently, but they're all for games I don't play. The problem is, when the event is starting, a new Steam window pops up and flashes until I address it.

Is there any way to opt out of these invitation pop ups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, your only option is leaving the group entirely, it seems.

There's a [suggestion thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=760223) on the Steam forums about this. It's been going since late 2008, and as far as I can tell, it still isn't possible.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping not to hear.  I guess I'll just deal with them for now.