# How can I stop invitation spam?

Tags: steam

Occasionally, I receive invitations to join a Steam group from people I've never met, and which are most likely just sock-puppet accounts to begin with.  However, 99% of the time, none of my friends are in these groups, which makes it rather pointless to join them (and add to [event spam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32128/how-can-i-pre-emptively-mute-steam-event-invitations)).

**Am I able to restrict group invitations so that they only originate from friends?** Other options would be to restrict invitations to only those groups that already contain a friend, or off entirely.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## "Am I able to restrict group invitations so that they only originate from friends?"

The short answer: **No.**

People have been complaining about this on the [Steam forums](http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2927315) for over a year. There is also a [suggestion for this feature](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3070784) on the Steam forums but alas, Valve in their infinite wisdom have not implemented this feature (hopefully some day they will).

### Can I do anything to mitigate the amount of group invites I am receiving?

Yes! You can:

- Set your Profile Status to "Friends Only"
- Don't join any groups on steam
- Don't join any servers
- Block all communications with a person

I personally only do one of the above, and that is set my profile to "Friends Only". I haven't received any Group invites in a long time since doing that. 
Some servers have a plugin to automatically invite you to their group when you join their server. I mostly only play on competitive servers so this hasn't affected me.
If you're finding one particular person is harassing you non-stop with invites, you can Block all communications with that person.

Also,["You shouldn't be invited to a group after declining an invite to it just once."](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2178000)

Comment: Put a character that is late in the alphabet in front of your name. When I preceed my name with a clan tag which starts with a number, like 3E|Username, then I get way more invites to random groups than when I have my usual username which starts with a S.

Comment: +1 to @user28015 - My username used to start with two 00s, like 00|username|00 and I got so much invite spam it was ridiculous. I never realised that after I changed it to start with 'zz' how little invite spam I get. I figured people just stopped trying to get me to sign up.

Comment: Well, assuming that people are using bots for that, it is logical.